# Relation between $\Delta E$ and $\Delta p$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

This will be a very quick question. I've seen in some books, that when describing the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, it was used implicitly the application of the following statement:

$$\Delta E=\frac{(\Delta p)^2}{2m}$$

where $E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ is the energy of a free particle.

You can see an example of this, in the following printscreen of Gasiorowicz's book:

---

[image]

---

My question is the following:

> Is it correct to say, in this case, that the dispersion of the squared momentum is the same as the squared dispersion of momentum?:
>   $$\Delta p^2=(\Delta p)^2$$

(I've this question because I know that in statistics this statement is false.)

Comment: I don't believe that the first equation you wrote down for delta(E) is true. It certainly isn't true for the classical case where there is an object with an error delta(p) in its momentum measurement and, therefore, an error delta(E) in its kinetic energy. In that case the error delta(E) in kinetic energy would be p*delta(p)/m to first order.

Comment: I will show you a print of the book's section where I found this approximation

Comment: And I agree with what you said.

Comment: I see. I think that the context here must be that average p is equal to zero. In that case, the first order error that I wrote above is equal to zero and so one must go to 2nd order correction, which does give a classical expression corresponding to the first equation that you wrote. Anyway, in answer to your question delta(p^2)=(p+delta(p))^2=p^2+2*p*delta(p)+delta(p)^2. If the average p is equal to zero, then both the 1st and 2nd terms on the right side of the equation equal zero, so I believe that delta(p^2)=delta(p)^2. Again, this only holds if the average p is equal to zero.

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote delta(p^2)=(p+delta(p))^2=p^2+2*p*delta(p)+delta(p)^2. I think we just need to do a 2nd order Taylor expansion of $p^2$ around $\langle p \rangle$: $\Delta (p^2)=p^2-\langle p \rangle^2=2\langle p \rangle\Delta p +(\Delta p)^2$.

Comment: I think that what you wrote in your last comment is basically the same as what I wrote. Your equation reduces to delta(p^2)=(delta(p))^2 if the time-averaged p of <p> is equal to zero.